# A duplicate question with a unique answer by a closer

Tags: discussion, bug, answers, close-reasons

In this question: [When do wings not matter?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65675/when-do-wings-not-matter) a closer Jaun had answered my question but yet he marked my question to another question which his answer would not make any sense.

I have seen where a user will answer a question but still mark the question unclear as well. Is this not misusing the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the scenario you've presented.

1. User 1 answered a question
2. User 2 found a possible duplicate
3. User 1 agreed that it is a duplicate

Is User 1 misusing the system? TL;DR No, they are not misusing the system.

---

Regarding the first point, User 1 is not required to search for duplicates before answering. ([Is it my responsibility to search for duplicates & vote to close before answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91180/392799))

> Unless you recall a specific question that you think is a duplicate, it's not an expectation that you do exhaustive searching to look for a duplicate.

Regarding the last point, it's been established that answering and voting to close are distinct things. ([Should a user be allowed to vote to close a question that he has answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116069/392799))

> To that end, I see answering and voting to close as two separate and distinct actions.

Because User 1 was not aware of the possible duplicate, User 1 answered. User 1 *became aware* of said post, User 1 voted as they saw fit.

User 1 has nothing to gain from said actions above. *On the contrary,* if they voted leave open, one could allege (without proof) that they want fresh fake internet points, especially if a question hits the hot network questions list.